# Magento 1 : HEADERS ALREADY SENT (Systemlog)

Tags: magento-1.9, system.log

```
DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] Root/SITE/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] Root/SITE/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] Root/SITE/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] Root/SITE/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] Root/SITE/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
[5] Root/SITE/app/Mage.php:684
[6] Root/SITE/index.php:83
\</pre>
```

Comment: already remove echo , print_r and  readfile in controllers

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670031/magento-debug-headers-already-sent-error

Comment: i already tried and check file logs. @SukumarGorai

Comment: disable all third party extension and check

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the source of to the already sent data by adding:

```
headers_sent($file, $line);
Mage::log('Cannot send headers; headers already sent in ' . $file . ', line ' . $line);
```

in Mage_Core_Controller_Response_Http line #52

Comment: So when you've found where the headers are being sent, what then?